# D3: scrub (by scrolling) between the beginning and end of a transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scroll

Suppose you have a simple transition between two datasets. If I were to scroll 100px, could I have it transition between the beginning and end state based on my scroll position between 1 and 100px (the scroll amount is arbitrary). For example, at 50px, the transition is 50% complete. 90px the transition is 90% complete.

I've already tried starting and stopping `element.transition().duration( 0 );` the transition based on scroll events (by creating a function for scrollStart and scrollStop), but it's pretty janky.

I've seen this page [here](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/). My hunch is that this is overboard, since I'm transitioning between two datasets, and it's a linear transition. That said, the code is fairly advanced, so any explanation would be very helpful.